# Como calcular os pixels da area da imagem

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de calcular os pixels da area de uma imagem não é largura e altura pois trata-se de uma figura irregular, quero saber quantos pixels existem dentro desta figura, exemplo um triangulo, se calcular a altura x largura de um triangulo não irá dar o valor de sua área pois vai levar em conta como um quadrado. 
Já procurei bastante na internet e não encontrei nada que que me auxiliasse desde já obrigado!

Comment: Mas, afinal, você quer contar os pixels da imagem ou calcular a área dessa imagem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supondo que o fundo da imagem seja branco e o objeto da imagem (triângulo, por exemplo) seja preto, imagino que seja necessário percorrer cada pixel da imagem e verificar se a cor do mesmo (RGB) é preta. Se for, some 1 a variável da área. No fim, terá a quantidade de pixels que compõem o objeto da imagem (área).

Seria algo assim:

```
public static double percentualBrancos(BufferedImage img)
{
    double area = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y &lt; img.getHeight(); y++)
        for (int x = 0; x &lt; img.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            Color pixel = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
            if ((pixel.getRed() == 0) && (pixel.getGreen() == 0) && (pixel.getBlue() == 0))
                area++;
        }
    return area; 
}
```

Comment: Na verdade esta imagem que irei calcular ela foi recortada e salva em um arquivo .png, obrigado pela resposta irei testar sua ideia e ver se funciona em uma imagem recortada, pois o fundo da imagem em .png é transparente.

Comment: Então se o fundo é todo da mesma cor, naquele "IF" do código que respondi, é só testar se a cor é transparente. Se não for, area++, ou seja é a imagem em si.